# Where does woocommerce store product attribute tittle

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've been inspecting woocommerce database scheme, most of the details make sense except i can't seem to find in which table the attribute title is stored. The sample product in the image has different selections for product colour , i can see the attribute coulour values from the database , but i can't seem to find where the `colour attribute tittle gets stored` , look at the red arrow to see the detail am asking about.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

1. The entire attribute category is stored in 'wp_term_taxonomy' table
   with a prefix 'pa_'.
   [image]
2. The entire attribute’s value is stored in 'wp_terms' table with
   their name and slug. To link the attributes to the product
   Woocommerce use 'wp_term_relationships' table to store the mapping
   of the post/product ID with the term ID.

[image]

3. Lastly, WooCommerce keep all the assigned attribute name as a
   serialized way in 'wp_postmeta' table under meta_key =>
   _product_attributes.
   [image]

So to resume: Attributes names are displayed from '_product_attributes' meta_key and the values are displayed from 'wp_terms.name'.

It's all in the database but I don't recommend accessing the data directly from the database, use the built-in functions instead.

Answer (score 2):

Product attributes are one of the not-so-nice-things in WooCommerce. They look like a taxonomy, but aren't.

The attributes name is stored in `wp_woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies`

You may have a look into WooCommerce' documentation to find filters for attributes: https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/hooks/hooks.html

Answer (score 0):

Product Attributes are now stored in wp_postmeta with rows having meta_key as _product_attributes